# Tag density plot form chip or atac seq data

Tags: chip-seq

I m quoting this  [paper](https://www.cell.com/cell-stem-cell/fulltext/S1934-5909(17)30429-0?innerTabgraphical_S1934590917304290=) [image: figure], figure B where they write

"B) Violin plots for the normalized ATAC-seq ***tag density*** for all peaks within the indicated OC/CO groups at the indicated time points. Data were converted to a Z score based on the row-wise SD for each peak. ∗p < 0.01 Mann-Whitney U test."

My question is where is this tag density information coming from.

So far for chipseq data what I have done is

- Aligned the data
- Then all required data processing post alignment
- Generated bed and bigwig files of respective samples required for comparison
- Made tag-directory using homer.
- Then peak-calling using homer,annotated peak using homer.

Now so far I am not able to figure out where is this tag-density information is .

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Homer` to retrieve tag densities, quoting from their [manual](http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/ngs/quantification.html):

> **Calculating ChIP-Seq Tag Densities across different experiments**
>
> annotatePeaks.pl is [a] useful program for cross-referencing data from
>   multiple experiments.  In order to count the number of tags from
>   different sequencing experiments, you must first create tag
>   directories for each of these experiments.  Once created, tag counts
>   from these directories in the vicinity of your peaks can be added by
>   specifying "-d   ...".  You can
>   specify as many tag directories as you like.  Tag totals for each
>   directory will be placed in new columns starting on column 18.  For
>   example:
>
> annotatePeaks.pl pu1peaks.txt mm8 -size 400 -d Macrophage-PU.1/
>   Bcell-PU.1/ > output.txt

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is actually? Reads per base pair?

Comment: @StupidWolf, I cannot seem to understand the question, could you please provide more context?

Comment: Sorry @haci typed too fast, I meant what is "tag density" exactly. I don't use Homer, so when I read the publication pointed out in the original question, I assume it's something like reads per bp of the peak?

Comment: In my understanding it is the number of reads in a given genomic region or peak, in that respect it would be analogous to gene counts. I also found a similar [Q&A on this:](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=74730)

Comment: I finally landed up here http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/ngs/quantification.html